# .dataTable() pagination breaks class .click responsiveness

Tags: datatables

When I construct a normal table and give each column a distinct class, the classes are responsive for all rows. However, when I call .dataTable() on my table, only page 1 of the paginated results is responsive. Page 2 and beyond are not responsive.

Example code:

```js
var dataTableID = 'questionsTable';

var columns = {
    questionID: "ID",
    CategoryString: "Cat",
    difficultyLevel: "Diff",
    timesAsked: "Qty",
    questionText: "Question Text"
};

// my own little function that builds the HTML table. <TD> classes are column names   
//-- eg .questionID, .CategoryString, etc
var tableHTML = makeTable(questions, columns);

$('#' + dataTableID).html(tableHTML);

// dataTable works nicely except only page 1 .click is responsive!
$('#' + dataTableID).dataTable();

// works fine if I remove .dataTable() above. ONLY works for first page of results  
// if I keep .dataTable()
$('.questionID').on("click", function() {
    alert('Click called');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using pagination, dataTables change the visible rows by moving `<tr>`'s back and forth the DOM. `$('.questionID').on` is processed for columns on the first page *only*, since those columns is the only visible (accessible) columns after initialization.

So you must assign the click handler (or whatever you want to attach) on page change rather than on initialization. Here by the use of the `fnDrawCallback` event :

```js
function clickHandler() {
   alert('Click called');
}

var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    fnDrawCallback : function() {
       $('.questionID')
        .off("click", clickHandler)
        .on("click", clickHandler)        
    }        
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/U9Jmg/**

Notice the use of `.off`. dataTables actually moves the `<tr>`'s back and forth the DOM and a table in memory, including any attached events. If previous attached events is not released, we will end up in multiple alerts for each column.

Also note I have only used only one class `.questionID` for all the columns in the demo. The example is 1.10.x but this works in 1.9.x as well.

---

As you can see of the comments below, you could also use a delegated event instead of direct event binding. It changes the setup and perhaps it is not suitable for your needs, but anyway :

```js
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.questionID', clickHandler);
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/L29Dq/**

Comment: Good advice about not attaching the handler multiple times. According to [this](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html) the handler doesn't have to be reattached on redraw when attaching to the table rows. Any idea why this works?

Comment: @TPete, this is the difference between direct vs delegated events. See http://api.jquery.com/on/. In the datatables.net example you are refering to there are used a delegated event, that is only one event on `<tbody>` triggered when any of the inner elements `<tr>` is clicked. In my answer I use direct binding, an event for each visible column holding the class `.questionID`. You can do both. In your answer, you are using direct binding without cleaning up, resulting in multiple events, see example -> http://jsfiddle.net/e3633/

Comment: Very clear and thorough answer. I agree with TPete - really nice advice re. avoiding multiple attaches of the handler.

Comment: Back and forth `[through, across, over, around, under, on, in]` the DOM?

Comment: hey @Jongosi, not sure I understand your point - but if it is my poor, poor english, you are more than welcome to correct my language errors!!!

Comment: Hi @davidkonrad your English is great, I was just looking to clarify how Datatables moves the `tr` sets around the DOM. The fiddle helped tho, thx.

Answer (score 1):

When using `DataTables` pagination feature (as you do), only the first page of your data is present in the dom when you attach the click event handler. That's why the handler is attached to the elements on the first page and only to those elements.

When going to another page, DataTables will redraw the table which in effect removes the attached event handler. You have to reattach the event handler after every table draw. The [drawCallback](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option should be the right place for that:

```
$('#' + dataTableID).dataTable({
    "drawCallback": function(settings){
        $('.questionID').on("click", function(){
            alert('Click called');
        });
    }
});
```

As @davidkonrad pointed out in his answer, the click handler should be removed (using off) to avoid handling the event multiple times.

---

The DataTables page has a section on this as well: [Advanced Initialisation - DOM/jQuery events](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html). The example there uses delegated events.